# C++ Win10 programmatically determine manual lock and OS lock?

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I have a driver that enable/disable a sensor depending on whether OS is locked manually or left until OS locks automatically.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can check `GetLastInputInfo `

Comment: Why do you wan't to do that in the first place ? sounds somewhat fishy..

Comment: @darune I want to enable sensor if user locks manually, otherwise disable the sensor.

Comment: @VTT thanks for suggesting. I'm thinking I could determine the last user input by `GetLastInputInfo` and if its less than a second or so, I'll consider it manual lock